# error when running persistence test(JUnit) on spring

Tags: java, spring, junit, persistence

I created the backend of my application using spring for the first time. I wrote my first persistence layer test. Which just aims to write and read from my persistence layer. However, I'm getting the following error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ca.mcgill.ecse321.petshelter.dao.TestPetShelterPersistence': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ca.mcgill.ecse321.petshelter.dao.ClientRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Even after a lot of research I can't find any fix for it.

here is my client repository:

```
package ca.mcgill.ecse321.petshelter.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ca.mcgill.ecse321.projectgroup16.Client;


public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, String> {

    Client findClientByEmail(String email);

}
```

and here is my test class:

```
package ca.mcgill.ecse321.petshelter.dao;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Month;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import ca.mcgill.ecse321.projectgroup16.Client;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Client.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestPetShelterPersistence {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository; 

    @Test
    public void testCreateClientAndFind() {

        Client u = new Client(); 
        u.setName("joseph");
        u.setEmail("joseph.bouassaf@mail.mcgill.ca"); 

        clientRepository.save(u);

        Client b = clientRepository.findClientByEmail("joseph.bouassaf@mail.mcgill.ca");
        assertNotNull(b);
        assertEquals("joseph.bouassaf@mail.mcgill.ca",b.getEmail());
    }
}
```

I apologize if there is a lot of code and thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you share with us your `Client` configuration class?

Answer (score 1):

Annotate `ClientRepository` class with @Repository annotation. Without this, ClientRepository cannot be autowired.

```
@Repository
    public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, String> {

        Client findClientByEmail(String email);

    }
```

Comment: I did but it still did not fix it